# What's the best way to maintain a writable DB slave which is always overwritten by the master?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication

I need to replicate our main server's databases (MariaDB) to a local server in our office, which will be used as an offline mirror when we have connectivity issues.

The data on the master should *always* take priority over the data on the local slave. Our users will be instructed never to write anything to the local "offline" slave, however it will still need to be writeable to enable auth & sessions.

I believe that with a standard Master-Slave setup, this will create problems with data consistency.

Short of writing a shell script to drop & re-migrate all of the databases, & reset the replication logs when the connection is re-established, is there a better way to configure such replication natively with MariaDB or Galera?

Comment: Why do you think normal master-slave replication won't work for this? This is exactly what it's intended for.

Comment: Because when users access the local mirror, it will create entries in the local database for sessions & logging. Now when the master reconnects, will the data from the master *overwrite* the rows on the slave, or simply *add* them on the slave?

Comment: I missed that you said a *writable* DB slave. With master-slave, the slave should be read-only. I'm not sure how to do bidirectional replication with MySQL.

Comment: Consider a Galera cluster.

Comment: @RickJames I'm looking at my options with Galera, however I'm still unsure/doubtful it can do what I'm after. My particular scenario is to specifically allow split-brain/partitioning of the local mirror, with it then being resolved by  automatically dropping all of the local changes in favour of the changes on the master. It's a very untraditional approach, as it allows for planned data loss.

Comment: To get "eventual consistency", use MySQL's NDB Cluster.  It is more complex to set up and administer, but it is more powerful in the area you seem to need.  (Since "cluster" is ambiguous, I included "NDB".)

Answer (score 1):

You could use symmetricds to perform the bidirectional replication. It allows for conflict management in which you can define which side wins in the conflict in your case the master.